# grabbing the value of a text field and applying it elsewhere automatically

Tags: php, jquery

if i have a text field like this:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="txtquantity">
```

what i am trying to figure out is how can i grab the value of that text field and append it to a link like this:

index.php?quantity=(the value)

if this is done with jquery how would i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if you are trying to do this on the page the input gets posted to, or the current page. If you are trying to do it on the page the form gets posted to you would need to use PHP like the following.

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="'.$_GET['txtquantity'].'" />';
?>
```

However, if you are trying to do it before the form is submitted then using jQuery you would do it like this,

```
$("a").attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + $("#txtquantity").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
<a id="your_link_id" href="whatever">A Link</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#your_link_id').attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + $('#txtquantity').val(););
```

Comment: thanks, but what if the link is dynamic something like this: actions.php?action=add&p=a52c582ecdba458b805c057764771fe2&quantity= how can i search for the param quantity and append the value after the equals sign?

Comment: @Honey: If you have links like `actions.php?action=add&p=a52c582ecdba458b805c057764771fe2&quantity=`, i have updated my code for that. Because `&quantity=` is already there in the link, the code get the url of the link including `&quantity=` and appends value of the textbox with specified it.

Comment: What do you mean "search" for the param quantity? Are you planning on having actions.php?action=add&p=a52c582ecdba458b805c057764771fe2&quantity= set as your href? Or is there going to be more attached onto there and you need to actually find the quantity param in the string.